# Viewvc not expanding keywords

Tags: svn, viewvc

I just noticed that, the svn keywords are not expanded while viewing the files through ViewVC. The svn properties are set properly and I am able to view the expanded keywords, if I checkout the files to a unix machine. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ViewVC doesn't support keywords now, check [this issue](https://github.com/viewvc/viewvc/issues/73).